# UWP: how to Cleanup properly a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, uwp, mvvm-light, viewmodellocator

I have developed an UWP app that uses **MvvmLight**, but there are some **memory leaks**.
My app contains 2 main pages:

- the **Home** page, containing a list of forms
- the **Details** page, containing all the details of the selected form (datas, photos, ...)

Each time that I open the **Details** page, I can see that **25 more Mo are used by the memory**: so after a dozen of page loadings, the application becomes slower...

My ViewModels inherit from **ViewModelBase**, so I can use **Cleanup()**.

So I try to use it in **DetailsViewModel** like this:

```
public override void Cleanup()
{
    Messenger.Default.Unregister<SendImageOnDetailsViewModel>(this);
    Messenger.Default.Unregister<SendDeletedImageOnDetailsViewModel>(this);
    VComponentBoms = null;
    VComponentOrders = null;
    VCoreOrders = null;
    CarForm = null;
    base.Cleanup();
}
```

I call it directly on the **DetailsViewModel**, after the user saved a form, before he's coming back to the **HomeViewModel**:

```
Cleanup();
NavigationService.NavigateTo<HomeViewModel>(this, new object[] { }, "RefreshForms", new object[] { }, false);
```

I also call it when the user is coming back to the Home page through the **Back button**, through **AppBackButtonPressed()** in **App.xaml.cs**:

```
if (cur.GetType() == typeof(DetailsViewModel))
{
    cur.Cleanup();
    GC.Collect();
}
```

This works without error, but it doesn't seem to be the good way to implement it...

On some samples, the **Cleanup()** is raise on the **Closing event** of the page, which doesn't exist on UWP.

So is there a cleaner way to do this with UWP?

Comment: How do you cache page (NavigationCacheMode)? Btw you shouldn't use GC.Collect()...

Answer (score 1):

Without a complete repro of what you're doing it's hard to be certain but it looks like the problem isn't with cleaning up ViewModels but the pages used to display them. If you keep navigating forward you'll end up with multiple pages each using up memory. (The memory profiling tools will show you where the memory is being used and you should use these to verify what the actual issue is.)

Assuming the issue is multiple pages being created then after viewing the details page you should navigate back to the main page, not forward to it.
If you go forward then another copy of the main page will be created and this duplication of page and content will be the cause of the leak.
If you go back then the page you've left can be collected. Note that this won't necessarily be done immediately though.

If you're still getting the issue with memory leaking when you do navigate back from the details page to the main page then the issue will be something in the details page preventing the memory being collected. More detail (and ideally a repro) will be needed to identify the cause.